# How find ssh folder from jGit

Tags: git, jgit

I want to find `.ssh` folder from java code, using `jGit` library. I have `git bash` installed. The code should work on both Linux and windows. What are the ways to find it?

Comment: Can I get this folder path from command line?

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is `ls- *.ssh`this should list all SSH files in a folder. more about globbing here...
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Comment: It will find ssh folders for all users and not works for windows.